# Updating multiple rows using WHERE... IN

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I may have gone mad here, but shouldn't this work?

```
UPDATE clients SET ClientArchive = '1' WHERE ClientID IN (37,38,46,51, ...)
```

**clients** is a table; **ClientID** is an autoupdating integer in that table; **ClientArchive** is a boolean Tinyint(1). All I want is to change a bunch of values at once. I get this output from phpMyAdmin 4.8.0.1:

> 0 rows affected. (Query took 0.0002 seconds.)

MariaDB 5.5.57, PHP 5.6.36

Comment: Do you get results if you just do `SELECT * FROM clients WHERE ClientID IN (37,38,46,51, ...)`

Comment: The number of affected rows shows how many records were really changed. The records where ClientArchive is already equal to '1', will not be counted. Maybe this is the reason?

Comment: If you already run the query once and didn't change any of the updated row then running the query again will not affect any row

Comment: Thanks all. I think I've confused myself... If I do
`SELECT * FROM clients WHERE ClientID IN (37,38,46,51, [...])`
I get rows all of which have ClientArchive = 1, so the UPDATE query did work. My confusion has come from a php page I created which should list all rows where ClientArchive=0 AND a "last modified" date is less than 3 years ago, and it's still showing all the rows in that IN() list for some reason. I'll go back and check the code again...

Comment: Cheers all. I'd got the list of IDs from the wrong source (doh). Long story short, it's now fixed and works as it should, using the code as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the ClientArchive is a boolean the try using 1 (instead of '1')

```
    UPDATE clients 
    SET ClientArchive = 1 
    WHERE ClientID IN (37,38,46,51, ...)
```

and check the result using a query  not the ide response

```
    select *
    from clients
    where  ClientID IN (37,38,46,51, ...)
    and ClientArchive <> 1
```